# Angular Material table spec

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a component that render a table using Angular Material `mat-table`. It is working fine, but in my spec file the table does not render the elements of the body (`td`s and `tr`s), so the test fails.
It seems that I initialize the text correct, I import the `MatTableModule`, and also initialize the datasource for the `mat-table`.

The component get input which goes to the datasource, it not async, and I call `fixture.detectChanges()` after initializing the input.

The `table` and `body` tags are rendered but the `body` tag is empty.
Any suggestions why the data of the `table` is not rendered?

Thanks

here is a sample of the test code:

```js
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
const dataSource: DataSource[] = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}];

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations:[MyComponent],
        imports: [MatTableModule],
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement
});

it('should display results', () => {
    component.myDataSource = dataSource;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    console.log(debugElement.nativeElement); //here I see that the body is empty

    const elements = debugElement.queryAll(By.css('td'));
    expect(elements.length).toBe(2); // I get 0
});
```

Comment: I have edit the post

Comment: By the way, does it work properly and only the test fails? I mean it renders when you local debug your application?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `MatTableDataSource`, declaring table containing array of object, initializing with `new MatTableDataSource<type>(array)` and don't forget to check the column definitions, because the table doesn't render if the definitions cause an error (e.g. it doesn't find some column etc.)

Comment: Any chance of showing us the source of the test-case?

Comment: Shouldn't the datasource declaration be something like: component.myDataSource= new MatTableDataSource(someArray); So it creates the binding.

Comment: not according to he first example here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: Before I moved to material table my test was green

Comment: Sorry about that. If you show us your components code that might help a bit. Does the table render properly when you devtest?

Comment: Yes, in dev it does.